# Reload Apache Using ACME User

Tags: apache2, sudo, debian-buster

I run a web server on Debian 10 (Buster) and Apache 2.4.38. I created a special user `acme` that runs scripts for renewing TLS certificates.

```
$ cat /etc/passwd | grep ^acme
acme:x:1002:1002::/var/acme:/usr/bin/nologin
$ cat /etc/group | grep ^acme
acme:x:1002:
```

This `acme` user should be allowed to reload the Apache 2 configuration after the certificates were renewed. So I added this line to my `/etc/sudoers` using `visudo(8)`:

```
%acme   ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work:

```
$ sudo -u acme /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
[....] Reloading apache2 configuration (via systemctl): apache2.serviceFailed to reload apache2.service: Access denied                                                                                                                  
See system logs and 'systemctl status apache2.service' for details.                                                                                                                                                                     
 failed!
```

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **BE** the user acme when you run sudo, not with `-u acme`.

```
acme@host:~ $ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

Another possible issue:

The `%` in your sudoers file denotes that `acme` is a group. This is not an issue when your user is in a group called `acme`, but it is if he is not.

Comment: OK, I got it, since the whole process will be started as `acme`, I can use `sudo` instead of `sudo -u acme` in my script. That works!